Correlated SQL Query does not work with aggregate count function
Error: syntax error at or near "select"
select count(
    select product_id FROM orders as o1 WHERE o1.product_id = p1.id
) as num_orders FROM products as p1;


Why don't you write this :
SELECT count(product_id) 
FROM   orders as o1 
       JOIN products as p1 
          ON o1.product_id = p1.id;

?
